# How do you access a dynamic text field from a package / class?

Tags: actionscript-3, class, package, undefined, textfield

I tried the following line of code inside a class, but it results in an errormessage.

```
textbox1.text = this.attribute1;
```

Error description: 1120: Access of undefined property textbox1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
package yourpackage
{
   public class MyClass
   {
      public var dynamicText:TextField;
      public function MyClass(){
          dynamicText = new TextField();
      }
   }
}
```

Now you can create a new `instance` from this class:

```
package yourpackage
{
   public class MyOtherClass
   {
      public var myInstance:MyClass;
      private var attribute1:int = 0;
      public function MyOtherClass(){
          myInstance = new MyClass(); //create new instance
          myInstance.dynamicText.text = String(attribute1); //set the text of it's
          //dynamicText textfield's text to the attribute you want
      }
   }
}
```

The error you get actually says that `textbox1` is not a defined variable in the current context, or the access modifier is private, thus you can't access it only from within the class. You can create `static` variables which you can access from anywhere like this:

```
MyClass.dynamicText.text = "something";
```

The above code assumes that you declared the `dynamicText` as a `static` variable.

```
public static var dynamicText:TextField = new TextField();
```

Comment: I don't understand. How can I have two public classes inside a package? I thougth that was illegal. And is your proposal to create a new textfield for every instance? I'm new to actionscript :)

Comment: If you are new to actionscript, and want to learn about it, then google the basics of it. Read about the packages, classes, access modifiers and programming patterns. To answer you rquestion, it is not illegal to have multiple classes in one package, packages are to organize your classes into groups. Read about access modifiers to see how you can manipulate the classes.

Comment: 5006: An ActionScript file can not have more than one externally visible definition: MyClass, MyOtherClass. I got this error.

Comment: That means that an ActionScript FILE can't have more classes, not packages. Files and packages are different things. You can sort your FILES in PACKAGES. Create a new .as file for every class you want, but in the same package.

Comment: What is the point of having several packages inside a .as-file when you can only have one class? If that's what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help! However I managed to access and change the text of my textfield by the following two lines of code inside my `clickHandler function`.

```
var r:MovieClip = MovieClip(root);
TextField(r["textbox1"]).text = this.navn;
```

Even though I didn't fully understand your code, I guess it involved creating a text field for each of the objects inside my class?

I will by the way, as you recommended, continue my reading on classes. :)
Thanks again.